# Dateformatter change the year of my date

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, nsdateformatter

I try to display a date with a dateformatter but this one change the year of the date.

This is the method :

```
setLabelWithDate:(NSdate *)date{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];    
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM YYYY"];

    NSLog(@"Date : %@",date);
    NSLog(@"stringFromDate %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

    self.selectedDateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

And this is what is displayed in the console :

```
2012-05-04 13:08:50.442 MyAppli[3339:fb03] Date : 2012-12-30 00:00:00 +0000
2012-05-04 13:08:50.443 MyAppli[3339:fb03] stringFromDate 30 December 2013
```

Here I m. The dateFormatter add myDate one year and I really don't know why. This case happens only for the 2 last dates of the year (30 and 31 december).

Thanks for your help.

Alexandre

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"]; // lowercase y
```

and you probably should check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) and [this](http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/).

Comment: It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Comment: Amazing answer. It just happened to me;) Bottle of wine for @Jonas Schnelli